# Skip processing of already processed nodes

Tags: xslt

Is there a way to avoid processing of already processed nodes?

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <node1>node1.1</node1>
    <node2>node2.1</node2>
    <node2>node2.2</node2>
    <node1>node1.2</node1>
</root>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node1">
        [Node1]:<xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node2"/>
        [End node1]
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node2">
            [Node2]:<xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        [Node1]:node1.1
            [Node2]:node2.1
            [Node2]:node2.2
        [End node1]

            [Node2]:node2.1

            [Node2]:node2.2

        [Node1]:node1.2
        [End node1]
```

As you can see template `<xsl:template match="node2">` is applied twice for every node2 element - one time from node1 template and second time when XSLT processor is transforming node2 element.

Is there any solution to avoid applying of `xsl:template match="node2"` second time?
I need to stop processing of node2 when I just processed it in template for node1.

**Important**
This example is just an emulation of more complex use case.
This means that we have additonal limitation - we can't modify template for root element processing.

I want to know if there is any way to stop processing of elements or move processing to some other elements.

Comment: So when *should* the `node2` template be applied? Only to those `node2` elements that occur before any `node1` elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mode` to name the template to use.

You can create an empty catch-all node that will output nothing, taking care of `apply-templates` calls that have no `select`.

The following stylesheet outputs what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node1">
        [Node1]:<xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node2" mode="fromNode1"/>
        [End node1]
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node2" mode="fromNode1">
            [Node2]:<xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node2"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the empty modeless template at the end, and the added `mode` attribute on the template and the calling `apply-templates`.

Comment: Ooh I hadn't considered mode - strong solution.

Comment: Do note that this is not grouping by preceding `node1`. So, a `node2` could be eventually proccess more than once

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="kNode2ByPrecedingNode1" match="node2"
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::node1)"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node1"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[Node1]: ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kNode2ByPrecedingNode1',
                                         generate-id())"/>
        <xsl:text>[End node1]&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node2">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;[Node2]: ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
[Node1]: node1.1
    [Node2]: node2.1
    [Node2]: node2.2
[End node1]
[Node1]: node1.2
[End node1]
```

**Note**: Two problems: you process `node2` more than once, from `root` rule with applying templates to **all** node children, and from `node1` rule; plus your `following-sibling::node2` expression doesn't distinguish wich `node2` follows some `node1`.

**Edit**: If you can't modify how `root` rule apply templates, then you would need modes for process and skip proccess:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="kNode2ByPrecedingNode1" match="node2"
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::node1)"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[Node1]: ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kNode2ByPrecedingNode1',
                                         generate-id())"
                             mode="output"/>
        <xsl:text>[End node1]&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node2"/>
    <xsl:template match="node2" mode="output">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;[Node2]: ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT doesn't track state and every apply-templates, for-each, etc will potentially produce "redundant" results, but this is entirely a problem in the design of the style-sheet - if you don't want to "process" a node more than once you need to change the appropriate templates and selects so it doesn't get handled more than once.

That would be fairly trivial for your example, but you said that your example isn't very representitive so I'd suggest you post something more complete if you're having problems.